# Getting number out of dataset python

Tags: python, dataset, arviz

I have a dataset, let's call it A, and when I print it looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x_dim_0: 2)
Coordinates:
  * x_dim_0  (x_dim_0) int64 0 1
Data variables:
    x        (x_dim_0) float64 158.0 725.2
```

but now I want to extract the 158.0 and 725.2 and save them in a separate array, but I can't figure out how to get the values. I have tried A.x, A.get(), etc. Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with `xarray.Dataset`, but it seems that [`xarray.Dataset.data_vars`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.data_vars.html#xarray.Dataset.data_vars) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me ```Data variables:
    x        (x_dim_0) float64 174.7 152.4 ``` but I'm still not sure how to separate that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first select which variable do you want, `x` in this case, in order to get a DataArray from the Dataset and once you have a DataArray use `.values`.

In this case it would be:

```
A["x"].values
# or what is the same A.x.values
```